# Шлюз в локальной сети

Tags: iptables, firewall, unix, сеть

Здравствуйте гуру - есть ситуация...

Машина с двумя карточками

```
eth0 - смотрит в интернет с ip xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
eth1 - смотрит в сеть с ip 192.168.1.1

lan_ip - машинка внутри сети - к которой хочется интернет хотя бы без днс (192.168.1.8)
```

*Единственный маленький нюанс это то что lan_ip это по сути копия машины с двумя карточками - единственное что на ней сделано так это отключен интернет полностью*

Хочется как обычно расшарить интернет и ничего не получается 
Перерыл уйму мануалов на тему "Шлюз" и "Правила iptables".
Поэтому в гугл не посылайте - все что нужно от туда я уже почерпнул и безрезультатно

на lan_ip
ping 8.8.8.8 - Network unreachable...

---

iptables-save

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.8 on Sat Jan 12 03:21:32 2013
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [6:292]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [3:228]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3:228]
-A POSTROUTING -o eht1 -j SNAT --to-source xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jan 12 03:21:32 2013
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.8 on Sat Jan 12 03:21:32 2013
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [685:53976]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [541:49177]
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.8/32 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.8/32 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jan 12 03:21:32 2013
```

---

sysctl -p

1. net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
2. net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
3. net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts = 1

....

---

не знаю нужно ли конфиги интерфейсов - вроде не маленький настроил все правильно..
Буду благодарен любому совету..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пакеты попадают на нат?

```
iptables -L -nv -t nat
```

какой шлюз у тех кому нужен инет?

```
route -n
```

Comment: 192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1

видимо не попадают - так как значение по нулям...